# If four boxes are arranged left to right and there are two possible states for each of two events in each box, how many configurations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

So... I have 4 boxes. The order of these boxes are important. So I define them as 1st box, 2nd box, 3rd box, 4th box, from left to right.

There are two unique events that can happen to these boxes.
They can be in state A1 or A2.
At the same time, they can be in state B1 or B2.
What are all possible configurations ever for this?

So one configuration could be: Box 1 --> A1, B1 | Box 2 --> A1, B1 | Box 3 --> A1, B1 | Box 4 --> A1, B1

Another one could be: Box 1 --> A1, B1 | Box 2 --> A2, B2 | Box 3 --> A1, B1 | Box 4 --> A2, B1

Comment: Unclear if I am misinterpreting your intent.  Each box has $(2^2)$ possibilities.  Then, there are $(4!)$ ways of ordering the boxes.

Comment: So theoretically how does that work? And also what pseudocode can output all those configurations?

Comment: If the order of the boxes is fixed, then the number of possible states is just $(2^2)^4$ since there are two states for each of the two events in each of the four boxes.  Try listing all the possible states for the first two boxes to see why this is so.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a binary number: $bbbbaaaa$. Where both $b$ and $a$ can take either $0$ or $1$. The 1st $a$ and first $b$ relate to the state of the 1st box. Your 2 examples would be represented by numbers: $00000000$ and $01000101$. This is an 8 bit number, and therefore there are $2^8$ combinations.

As far as the code goes, since it's just a number and you need $n$th digit to find the state of each box, you can simply iterate over numbers from $0$ to $2^8$ and look at the bits of the number. Here's an example in Java:

```
class Permutations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            String binary = padLeftWithZeros(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            System.out.println(binary + ", Box #2, B-state: " + isBitSet(i, 6));
        }
    }

    private static boolean isBitSet(int mask, int bitIndex) {
        int bitFilled = 1 << bitIndex;// fill nth bit with 1
        return (mask & bitFilled) > 0;// check mask has nth bit 1 or 0
    }
    private static String padLeftWithZeros(String s) {
        return String.format("%8s", s).replaceAll(" ", "0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that flicks through everything though? Should I not separate them out to two 4 bit bytes? And then for each unique byte on the left, i combine all possible bytes on the right? I guess it comes to the same thing. Are you sure mathematically this explores all configurations?

Comment: "_And then for each unique byte on the left, i combine all possible bytes on the right? I guess it comes to the same thing_" - yes, it does